# Load PDFs from local file share

Tags: adobe-embed-api

I'm developing a web app for in-house use and I'm looking for a better way to display PDFs.

I've played around with Adobe's 'Work with Local File' example from GitHub, [Adobe GitHub Example](https://github.com/adobe/pdf-embed-api-samples/tree/master/More%20Samples/Work%20with%20Local%20File), and it works great using the file picker to display a PDF.  Is it possible with Adobe's PDF Embed API to take a file located on a local file share and display the PDF?

I'm thinking I need to create a file promise but I'm not sure how to create that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can make a network request to load the PDF, the answer is no. Browsers generally can't read from local files unless a user action actually picks the file. If your local share can be made accessible via HTTP, then you would be good to go.